# Как решить проблему cross language upgrade failed sql server 2016?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Пытаюсь обновить sql server 2014 до sql server 2016, выдает ошибку: cross language upgrade failed sql server 2016. Как решить эту проблему?

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123052/how-do-i-fix-a-cross-language-installation-problem-in-sql-server-2008)

советуют удалить предыдущую версию базы. Это не подходит, хотелось бы найти нормальное решение с апдейтом.

Comment: А у вас не разные языки локализации версий 2014 и 2016?

Comment: Локализации может быть и разные, только я не знаю где ее посмотреть и как это исправить. Я пробовал устанавливать и русскую и английскую версию 2016, ошибка одна и та же.